# Adding permissions to google dvelopers console across 2 apps accounts

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

I have a google play app using push notifications with Google Cloud Messaging for Android.

I am following this guide to move my apps to a new account https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213

The existing google account which owns the project in the google developer console belongs to a business google apps account. So does the target account, in a different business.

Every time I try to add any outside account with either owner/edit/view permissions I get the following error.

```
The non-domain account: xxxx@yyyy.com can not be added to a domain project.
```

I have searched for settings to enable cross domain transfers or make the project non-domain related without success.

Strangely one of my projects has worked, but all of the others won't.

Comment: Do you manage to solve this?

Comment: Have you been able to do it?

Comment: No, google apps support (which I pay for) said that it wasn't their product and that they couldn't help, I would need to raise it with the  play developer support. Developer support won't speak to me without me signing up for a paid support plan.